# JSON.parse unexpected end of data fire fox addon

Tags: javascript, json, firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I using add-on builder  build an addon with basic functions:
- get comments (A) from page `http://youtube.com`.
- Call the web server process this text (A) and return json 
- replace (A) by (B) and show it for user
I got problem with request to server (see in Browser console have many line ) :

```
GET http://localhost:8084/Test/Test [HTTP/1.1 200 OK 8ms]
JSON.parse unexpected end of data fire fox addon.
```

But last request is success. **And my code do not change comment because it changed before request response**.

lib/main.js

```
var tag = "p";
var data = require("sdk/self").data;
var pageMod = require("sdk/page-mod");

pageMod.PageMod({
  include: "*.youtube.com",
  contentScriptFile: data.url("element-getter.js"),
  contentScriptWhen: "end"      
});
```

data/element-getter.js

```
var target = document.querySelector('#watch-discussion');

var observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
  mutations.forEach(function(mutation) {
    var commenttexts = document.querySelectorAll(".comment-text");
    for (var i = 0; i < commenttexts.length; ++i) {
          var url = "http://localhost:8084/Test/Test";        
          var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
          var cm = " hello ";
          request.open("GET", url, true);
          request.onload = function () {
            var jsonResponse = JSON.parse(request.responseText);
            var status = jsonResponse.status;
            cm = status;
          };
          request.send();             
          commenttexts[i].innerHTML = cm;
    }         
  });    
});
var config = { childList: true };
observer.observe(target, config);
```

json server return:

```
{"status":"1","label":"true"}
```

Comment: You probably want to do a forEach loop rather than a for loop so your XHR requests are in their own closures; this is currently overwriting `request` on each loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are creating an assynchronous request, so thist part:

```
commenttexts[i].innerHTML = cm;
```

should be called when the request responds, i.e. inside the request.onload function, not after the `request.send();`. Having it at the end, means it will run first that part, before the request comes back.

You should have something like this:

```
for (var i = 0; i < commenttexts.length; ++i) {
  (function(i) {
    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var cm = " hello ";
    request.open("GET", url, true);
    request.onload = function () {
        var jsonResponse = JSON.parse(request.responseText);
        var status = jsonResponse.status;
        cm = status;
        commenttexts[i].innerHTML = cm;
    };

    request.send();
  })(i);
}
```

This way it only gets changed when it comes back, and you have access to the i variable inside the onload function.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I got crash fire fox error when running add on and i don't know line code : i <  i < commenttexts.length

Comment: That's a typo. it should be only one i <